# ¿Porque no se visualiza un div usando mediaqueries en HTML?

Tags: html, html5, css

Tengo dos div uno con fondo amarillo y otro con fondo rojo, el fondo rojo se debe de ver en una resolucion mayor a 800px y el amarillo en la resolucion menor o igual a 800px, el div rojo funciona bien pero el amarillo no se visualiza al momento de verlo en un celular o acortar el ancho del navegador estoy usando mozilla firefox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
    @media screen and (max-width:800px)
    {
        .menu1
        {
            display:block;

        }

        .menu2
        {
            display:none;

        }
    }
</style>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div class='menu1' style='display:none;background:#FFFF00'>
    menu_celular
  </div>

  <div class='menu2' style='background:#FF0000'>
    menu_pc
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `CSS` es hojas de estilo en cascada, esto quiere decir que se iran
>   aplicando una tras otra.

---

En las propiedades de `CSS` hay prioridades en cuanto a que estilo aplicar y estas dependen de la forma en que incluyas `CSS` en tu código, ya que puedes tener:

**1)** Hojas de estilo importadas en `meta`.

```
// <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

**2)** Etiquetas de `style` dentro de `meta`.

```
// <style></style>
```

**3)** Etiquetas de `style` dentro de las etiquetas de HTML (conocido como `inline`).

```
// <input type="text" style='display:none;'>
```

---

La prioridad que toma CSS para elegir cual aplicar es esta:

**1)** Primero etiquetas de `style` dentro de elementos HTML (conocido como `inline`).

**2)** Archivos externos o incluidos en `meta` (puntos 1 y 2 de la anterior escala).

**3)** Estilo por defecto del navegador.

---

Es decir, que aunque tu codigo `CSS` este bien, cuando se active `@media` va a encontrar que debe ocultar el `menu2` y mostrar el `menu1`, pero cuando llega a `menu1` consigue que tiene `display:none` y lo ocultara por tener mas prioridad.

---

**¿Como se soluciona?**: pues quitamos la etiqueta de `style`del elemento y la colocamos como una clase así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
    .menu1{
        display:none;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:800px)
    {
        .menu1
        {
            display:block;

        }

        .menu2
        {
            display:none;

        }
    }
</style>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div class='menu1' style='background:#FFFF00'>
    menu_celular
  </div>

  <div class='menu2' style='background:#FF0000'>
    menu_pc
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

---

De esta manera, se aplica el `display:none` cuando estas por debajo de los `800 width` y cuando cambias a `@media` mostramos el `menu1`